# How to delete specific div element with Js?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to delete specific div element, when it is loaded another page than homepage. I wrote such js code:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        if (window.location.href != 'http://stackoverflow.com/')
            document.getElementById('panel').remove();

    }
</script>
```

I put it in   code and put in WIdget.

Html code:

```
<div id="panel">
bla bla bla 
</div>
```

It doesn't work anymore
I try also this:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
          var loc = http://stackoverflow.com/;
        if (window.location.href != loc)
            document.getElementById('panel').remove();

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried to remove the div outside onload function? Maybe this is the problem. Your .remove() it's correct.

Comment: What do you mean by "*when it is loaded another page than homepage*"? How is it "loaded"?

Comment: var loc = **"** http://stackoverflow.com/ **"**;

Comment: When it is not homepage and another page like stackoverflow.com/contact or stackoverflow.com/support

Answer (score 0):

I know that remove sometimes doesn't work, so try this:

```
Element.prototype.remove = function() {
    this.parentElement.removeChild(this);
}
NodeList.prototype.remove = HTMLCollection.prototype.remove = function() {
    for(var i = this.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(this[i] && this[i].parentElement) {
            this[i].parentElement.removeChild(this[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can remove elements like this

```
document.getElementById("my-element").remove();
```

Comment: I wouldn't modify the prototype of a native object for this. You can just make a function that accepts the element and removes it through its parentElement and removeChild in 2 lines.

Comment: That's right but he didn't wanted to create a parent div. This will result in an unnecessary wrapping div element.

Comment: @KyleRichardson It's fine for polyfilling (though should be properly documented as such)

Comment: @BarrJ No, I just made that in the example. Every element has a `parentElement`, unless you try to remove the `html` element for some reason.

Comment: @Bergi Ok, I'll defer to your judgement here.